# how to deploy crystal report while creating setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This Report run iin application and after create setup not working this error please solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: well - look at the exception and try to figure out what it is and why it is cause. but don't expect help from us while providing neither error details (for example the type of the exception) nor the code causing the error.

Comment: BTW, it seems a Winforms application,am i right? If so, shouldn't be tagged as asp.net

Comment: post the details of exception here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Project properties under Publish Option there is a button named Application. Under that option we can select the Applications that need to be included for the project to be runable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, select your report file properties and change **Compilation Action** to **Content**.

Then in your proyect properties, go to **Publish**, **Application Files**, and there you'll see your report file. You can change it to **Include** instead of **Include(Automatic)**.

This way your report would be deployed in your Click Once installation. Hope this helps.

Reference: [Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx)